# recursive batch-file for movin *.doc, *.pdf, etc

Tags: windows, batch-file, filesystems, move, xcopy

I recovered the files from a HDD with windows 7 installed
now I have a mess in a folder, with thousands and thousands of files and folders, I really don't know much about batch coding but by watching some youtube videos I could get to the next below, but that batch-file only looks for files in the current folder where I execute the batch, I want it to look in the folders inside that folder and so..
Sorry for my bad English

```
@echo off

move /y "*.xml" "D:\backUP_arqui\Recovered data 03-10 20_23_41\Deep Scan result\xml"

move /y "*.pdf" "D:\backUP_arqui\Recovered data 03-10 20_23_41\Deep Scan result\documentos"

move /y "*.cat" "D:\backUP_arqui\Recovered data 03-10 20_23_41\Deep Scan result\cat"

move /y "*.dll" "D:\backUP_arqui\Recovered data 03-10 20_23_41\Deep Scan result\dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
@echo off
for /R %temp% %%f in (*.*) do (
echo %%f )
```

There you can see a for-loop with the parameter "/R". "/R" makes the loop recursive to look also into the subfolders.

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for /D /R %%a in (*) do (
 pushd "%%a"
 move /y "*.xml" "D:\backUP_arqui\Recovered data 03-10 20_23_41\Deep Scan result\xml"
 move /y "*.pdf" "D:\backUP_arqui\Recovered data 03-10 20_23_41\Deep Scan result\documentos"
 move /y "*.cat" "D:\backUP_arqui\Recovered data 03-10 20_23_41\Deep Scan result\cat"
 move /y "*.dll" "D:\backUP_arqui\Recovered data 03-10 20_23_41\Deep Scan result\dll"
popd
)
```

This should execute the series of commands in all directories from the source.

The `SETLOCAL` is optional - it ensures that any changes to the environment are discarded when the bathc ends. There are none in this case, but it's common practice regardless.

The `for /d` instruction assigns each directoryname matching the mask `*` in turn to `%%a`. The `pushd` temporarily sets the default directory to that name, the `move` instructions are executed and the `popd` restores the original directory.

Be careful though - remember that if any file `x.ext` is found more than once, the very last one with that name will be moved, replacing any others.

Perhaps

```
xcopy /s *.xml "D:\backUP_arqui\Recovered data 03-10 20_23_41\Deep Scan result\"
```

may help. It will copy all `.xml` files from the source to the destination, building the same directory structure under the destination directory as exists under the source directory. In that way, you'd have a copy of the original files in case there is a duplicated name. Obviously,  you would need to repet the instruction for each filetype you require.

Comment: you can also write it to create a directory for each file extension automatically, but that is very dangerous, :)